# Div changes its size after sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a small script (the full code of the web-page is placed below) that adds some divs to a sliding panel activated by a button click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Click the button and let the panel slide.
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $('.panel').slideToggle('slow');
    });

    // Insert a huge amount of divs.
    var divsToPlace = 100;
    for (i = 0; i < divsToPlace; i++) {
        $( '<div/>', {'class': 'addDiv'}).appendTo('#addHere');
    }
</script>
```

Divs are really specific. They form some kind of a puzzle: 100 squares 10 by 10, sticking together. They shouldn't create a new line for each of them and they should be empty inside.

```
  .addDiv {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-top: -1px;        /* these two provide a "net" */
    margin-right: -1px;
    float: left;             /* doesn't allow divs to start from a new line. */
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
  }
```

And so the result that I desire is a panel which has a "net" in it.
Divs must be inserted by a script, that's very important.

But the problem is that the bottom border of the panel hops up right after animation stops. And the divs remain between the panel and the body of the page.

I have no idea how to fix this and I ask for your help.

Full code is inserted here, so you can easily try it:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
  #header {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .addDiv {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    float: left;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
  }
  .panel {
    border: 1px solid #666;
    display: none;
    margin: auto;
    width: 305px;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='header'><button id='button'>Panel</button></div>
  <div class='panel'>
    List:
    <ul>
      <li>li 1</li>
      <li>li 2</li>
    </ul>
    <div id='addHere'></div>
  </div>
</body>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $('.panel').slideToggle('slow');
    });

    var divsToPlace = 100;
    for (i = 0; i < divsToPlace; i++) {
        $( '<div/>', {'class': 'addDiv'}).appendTo('#addHere');
    }
</script>
</html>
```

P.S. And if I to refer a lot to one element what should I do:

```
// This way?
/* ... code
$('#element').thing();
$('#element').another_thing();
... code ...
$('#element').more_thing();
code... */

// Or this way?
/* ... code
var element = $('#element');
element.thing();
element.another_thing();
... code ...
element.more_thing();
code... */
```

Comment: create a js fiddle with this and it would be easier to help you.

Comment: For starters I would create divs with only right and bottom margins, so you don't have to do the trick with the negative margins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two ways to fix this issue.
1) Add the float attribute to the parent div (.panel)
2) Remove float attributes from .addDiv and instead use display:inline-block. Create a new rule to remove the line-heights in #addHere. See this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/QeADw/

```
.addDiv {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-right: -1px;
    margin-top:-1px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
  }
#addHere{
    line-height:1%;
}
```

Hope this helps.